# Calculate the closure of a set

Tags: general-topology

I have $A=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2 \mid |x|\leq1, y>x^2 \}$.

I have to calculate its closure, but I don't know how to prove that the points that verify $\ y=x^2$ belong to the closure.

I tried finding a succession that tends to $\ (x_0 ,\sqrt{\ 1-x_0 ^2})$, but wasn't able to.

I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: What do you know about the closure?  What characterizations do you have for the closure?

Comment: Why not pick a particularly simple point first - can you write down a sequence of points which tends to $(0,0)$? Can you modify it so it lies inside $A$? Can you generalize this to other points you care about?

Comment: Well, now I see I tried to find the succession with a circle and not the parabola (I don't know how I got to think it was I circle). Thank you for your tips.

Answer (score 1):

Let $B = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \, | \, |x| \leq 1, y \geq x^2\}$. To prove that $B$ is closed, consider for instance the continuous function $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ defined by $(x,y) \mapsto (|x|, y-x^2)$. Then $B$ is the preimage of the closed set $[0,1] \times [0, \infty)$ under this map, and hence is closed.

It remains to prove that $B$ is the closure of $A$. If there was a point of the form $(x,x^2)$ with $|x| \leq 1$ not contained in the closure of $A$, consider a sequence $(x_n) \subset [-1,1]$ such that $(x_n)$ converges strictly monotoneously increasing or decreasing to $x$, then $(x_n,x_n^2)$ is a sequence in $A$ converging to $(x,x^2)$. Then the closure of $A$ would be not closed, a contradiction.